# Tomcat not running on eclipse

Tags: windows, tomcat6, eclipse

In order to test the spring framework web services locally via Eclipse Mars, I am trying to setup Tomcat. When I tried to set it up on the servers tab, I could only see Tomcat v6 option. and not sure why it always says stopped whenever I try to start it after some time.Here is how it looks like at stopped stage:
[image]

And here is how it looks like in Server Runtime Environment(Also, I don't understand why Tomcat 7 or 8 isn't listed for Eclipse Mars. Tomcat 7 showing below was the one I added manually):

[image]

This is the error, I keep on getting every time if I try to start the server:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just been encountering a very similar issue in Ubuntu while trying to get Eclipse Mars and Tomcat7 integrated because Eclipse was expecting the tomcat configuration files etc to be all in the same location, and with the necessary permissions to be able to change those files.

The following instructions from this blog article helped me in the end:

cd /usr/share/tomcat7

sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf conf

sudo ln -s /var/log/tomcat7 log

sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy

sudo chmod -R a+rwx /usr/share/tomcat7/conf

Comment: I came across the article. Answer looks like copied from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962732/could-not-load-the-tomcat-server-configuration

I am on Windows by the way.